# Using Lastdate with if

Tags: powerbi, dax

First of all I'm still new to Power bi and Dax so please bear with me on this. Thank you

I want to add a new calculated column called Product Type and this will be based on per location.

On the sample table that I have below

product code aaa123 has 3 records with 3 different movement dates and 3 different locations.

I want to get the most recent movement date for product aaa123, then if the location is NSW then product A, if WA then product B

any suggestions?

| Product Code | Movement Date | To Location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aaa123 | 12 Nov 2022 | NSW |
| aaa123 | 31 Oct 2022 | ACT |
| aaa123 | 15 Nov 2022 | WA |
| bbb123 | 10 Nov 2022 | NSW |
| bbb123 | 14 Nov 2022 | NSW |
| bbb123 | 01 Nov 2022 | WA |
| ccc123 | 31 Oct 2022 | WA |
| ccc123 | 01 Nov 2022 | VIC |
| ccc123 | 02 Nov 2022 | QLD |
|  |  |  |

I was thinking of using the LASTDATE and IF DAX functions but I don't know how to proceed. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a solution using DAX alone:

```
=
VAR ThisProductCode = Table1[Product Code]
VAR LatestDate =
    CALCULATE(
        MAX( Table1[Movement Date] ),
        FILTER(
            Table1,
            Table1[Product Code] = ThisProductCode
        )
    )
VAR LatestLocation =
    CALCULATE(
        MAX( Table1[To Location] ),
        FILTER(
            Table1,
            Table1[Product Code] = ThisProductCode
                && Table1[Movement Date] = LatestDate
        )
    )
RETURN
    SWITCH(
        LatestLocation,
        "NSW", "Product A",
        "WA", "Product B"
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that this is an imported dataset, we can achieve this by using two steps.

**1st Step** ( Group by the data )

Go to Transform data -> select the table -> Transform -> Group By

[image: Transform Data]

Then do the group by as follows (Make sure you have correct data types for columns)

[image: Group By]

This will give you a table as follows.

[image: Group by table]

Now expand the table and select the columns as shown in the Screenshot.

[image: Expand table]

[image: Select columns]

Then add a conditional column by selecting add Column->Conditional column and add condition as per the Screenshot

[image: Conditional Column]

Please remove the Latest date column and change the "Is Latest" column data type to whole number

[image: Final table]

Then close and apply, then in the front select the table and add a New column

[image: Front end]

```
Product = 
IF (
    'sample data'[Is Latest] = 1,
    IF (
        'sample data'[To Location] = "NSW",
        "Product A",
        IF ( 'sample data'[To Location] = "WA", "Product B", BLANK () )
    ),
    BLANK ()
)
```

Table will look like below.

[image: Intended result]

Please upvote and accept my answer, cheers!!!

Comment: Let me try this approach. I'm still struggling with a full DAX so this might be more simple for me

Comment: Sure IT should work. Im more than happy to share my .pbix file with you.

Comment: @AndrewA Any luck regarding this method?

Comment: Hi Amila unfortunately due to my access restrictions, I wasn't able to try the method above.